# Dynamically get the result of a Func<T,bool> invocation

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, dynamic, lambda

I am trying to serialize something based upon meeting particular criteria.

To this end my original hope was to use attributes containing a lambda expression on an object's properties.

However, as this cannot be done I've settled for having a Func<T,bool> member within the class and passing the type (or first parameter type) and name of this Func through the property attribute. E.g.:

```
Func<SomeObject, bool> func = (p => p.Value == 4);
[FuncAtt(typeof(SomeObject), "func")]
public SomeObject PropertyName { get; set;}
```

In my serializer I need to call this Func<T, bool>.

Let's assume I have a Type t which is equal to typeof(SomeObject) in this case, or more abstractly, typeof(T).  I can also get the Func<T,bool> itself, but only through reflection as an object.

My naive approach is something along these lines:

```
object func = typeof(MyClass).GetField(attribute.FuncName).GetValue(MyClassInstance);
Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(attribute.Type, typeof(bool));

ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(attribute.Type, objectToSerialize);
LambdaExpression l = Expression.Lambda(funcType, func, p); /* Won't work */
```

But this leads to the problem of casting a lambda to a delegate which is apparently erroneous.

I tried this in place of 'func':

```
(Expression)((Action)(() => func))
```

But that relies on func being a method call not a lambda.

So, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do something like this, without need for expressions:

```
public static class Test
{
    public static Predicate<int> func = s => s > 20;
}
```

and to get the value:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a = typeof(Test).GetField("func");

        bool validates = ((Predicate<int>)a.GetValue(null)).Invoke(100);
    }
```

**edit** to get the value without knowing the type:

```
bool validates = (bool)((Delegate)a.GetValue(null)).DynamicInvoke(100);
```

Comment: I have a type variable, not the actual type and you can't go (Predicate<sometypevariable>)a.GetValue().  Can you still take this approach?

Comment: Yes, see my edit, with the cast to delegate and the DynamicInvoke.

Comment: Great! Thank you :-). Looks simplest solution and testing now.

Comment: Thanks for your code. It's really help me to sorted out my issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Compile method of a lambda expression to cast it to a delegate.

here's what I found on MSDN:

> The  Expression<(Of <(TDelegate>)>)
>   type provides the  Compile method,
>   that compiles the code represented by
>   the expression tree into an executable
>   delegate. This executable code is
>   equivalent to the executable code that
>   would have been generated had the
>   lambda expression been assigned to a
>   delegate type originally.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) you can find it.

Comment: Yes thanks, but I need an Expression to be able to Compile it.  As it is I cannot create the Expression.

Comment: Ah but I see an example there where I can simply go Expression<Func<SomeObject, bool>> = (lambda) in place of (Func<SomeObject, bool>>>).  I'll just make sure to reference Expressions rather than Funcs in my object classes.  Pity I can't find a way to convert the two dynamically.

Comment: isn't Func<T,T> a delegate ? why you want to convert it to a lambda expression ?

Comment: If there's a better way to get the result of evaluating the Func, bearing in mind that it is of type object, I'd love to know it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is working sample, but this is the way:

```
// not sure what are you doing in this line, but assume it should return
// a method name specified in the attribute, e.g. "func" in your example.
// Also "func" must be a method (static one in my example) of SomeObject class
String funcname = typeof(MyClass).GetField(attribute.FuncName).GetValue(MyClassInstance);
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeObject), "p");
MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(SomeObject, funcname, new Type[] { typeof(SomeObject), typeof(Boolean) }, param);
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeObject, Boolean>>(call, param);
```

now you can call the "func" method like this:

```
Boolean result = lambda.Compile()(SomeObjectInstance);
```

Comment: Hmm it looks like it might work, but bear in mind I don't know SomeObject, I just have a type variable representing it.  So I can't on the last line go Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeObject, Boolean>>.  But the non generic Lambda method may be able to help me.

Comment: I was also trying to avoid creating a full method wrapping the Func as the original problem is about decorating existing properties as easily as possible.